# mysql: find rows which have a field that is a substring of "string"

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

is there a way to write an sql query that finds all rows where the field value is a substring of a given string.

Example:

```
table names

Name      |      Nickname
rohit            iamrohitbanga
banga            rohitnick
sinan            unur
```

query should be something like

```
select * from names where Name is a substring of "who is rohit";   // to get first row
select * from names where Nickname is a substring of "who is rohitnick";   // to get second row
select * from names where Name is a substring of "who is unur and banga"
or Nickname is substring of "who is unur and banga";   // to get second and third row
```

How is it possible?

If it is not possible then i'll have to achieve that behaviour in java. i am using jdbc:mysql driver to connect to the database.

**Update**
your solutions work

now a bit of a twist.
if we want to check if a substring of the field occurs as a substring of the string that we specify.

```
select * from names where Name is a substring of "who is sina";   // to get third row
```

Comment: It's disrespectful to those who provided answers to change the criteria afterwards.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: I agree with `OMG Ponies`. Posters do not get notified that you changed your question, so most will not update their answers. If your initial problem is solved, accept an answer and feel free to add another question. Also, I do not see the difference between your new query (`Name is substring of something`) and the original queries (`Name is substring of something`)

Comment: the difference in the second one is that as shown in the example, sina is not a value of any cell, but it is a substring of sinan. so it must be matched. i'll try to solve this on my own. if i have trouble, i'll post a separate question.

Comment: and thanks for not voting me down for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of `Name` or `Nickname` has to be found within the text use

```
SELECT *
FROM names
WHERE instr("who is Rohit", Name) > 0
   OR instr("who is Rohit", Nickname) > 0
```

No index can be used for that, so it might take long for large tables.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with all these approaches is your indexes go right out the window.  You'll have to do a table scan for each and every row, which means your performance will only get worse and worse as the table size grows.

I'd rethink this approach if your table is going to be large.  Maybe you need a indexed searcher like Lucene.

Comment: i have lucene in mind. but right now for the prototype i want something simple.

Comment: a doubt that i do have is that my fields are typically small. so is it worth creating a Lucene `Document` for each row. Lucene would match documents based on tf/idf, which measures the frequency. so both my documents would be small. is lucene a good option.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE INSTR(Nickname,Name) > 0;
```

or, equivalently:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE LOCATE(Name,Nickname) > 0;
```

Comment: no. fireeyedboy seems to have done it correctly. i'll test that. anyhow you pointed out the same function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question then. :) But ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reverse the LIKE condition.

```
select * from names where "who is rohit" LIKE  CONCAT('%', Name, '%');
```

Note, this probably isn't any faster than  instr("who is Rohit", Name) but it may be.