# mysql: instr specify word boundaries

Tags: mysql, regex, word-boundary

i want to check if a string contains a field value as a substring or not.

`select * from mytable where instr("mystring", column_name);`

but this does not search on word boundaries.

`select * from mytable where instr("mystring", concat('[[:<:]]',column_name,'[[:>:]]');`

does not work either. how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 'mystring' REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', column_name, '[[:>:]]');
```

Note, however, that this is **slow**. You might be best off using [the MySQL's `FULLTEXT` search feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) if you care about words. Or do a normal `InStr()` check then filter the results.

Comment: cool, it works. i'll consider full index search later. right now it is a prototype. it seems we cannot specify word boundaries with instr(). right?

full text search in natural language was giving partial matches also, which would need to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, `InStr()` simply searches for a substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the return value of the `instr` use `like` instead

```
select * from mytable where column_name like '%mystring%';
```

Comment: can you tell me an example for your content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123738/mysql-find-rows-which-have-a-field-that-is-a-substring-of-string/2123783#2123783

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed in the question you [asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123738/mysql-find-rows-which-have-a-field-that-is-a-substring-of-string/2123783#2123783), no indexes can be used and performance is going to be bad, but this could work:

```
select *
from mytable
where 'mystring' = column_name                           -- exact match
   or 'mystring' like concat('% ', column_name)          -- word at the end
   or 'mystring' like concat(column_name, ' %')          -- word at beginning
   or 'mystring' like concat('% ', column_name, ' %')    -- word in the middle
```

Comment: this would match if the column_name string occurs as a substring of a word. it should match on word boundaries only.

Comment: No, it would not. It will match only if the query is surrounded by spaces/start/end. It won't match it when it's followed by a period though.

Comment: it is matching `mystringxyz` which is what i don't want. i tested it.

Comment: Did you paste the exact query with all spaces? Could you please try which one matches by trying the conditions separately?

Comment: why would index searches not work. i could not get your point yesterday also.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: You are right, actually. The matches should be `concat('% ', col)` (at end), `concat(col, ' %')` (at start) and `concat('% ', col, ' %')` (middle).

Comment: @Max S.: Thanks, don't know what I was thinking :) Corrected now.