# SQL - Find complete word in text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a text column in one of my tables in a MySql DB.
i want to get all the records that have a specific word in the text column.
for example:

```
ID,BIO
1, "i am a cto"
2, "i am a cto/developer"
3, "cto"
4, "i am a cto_developer"
5, "ctools"
```

In this case, when searching for "cto" I want the query to return records 1,2,3,4 but not 5.

Any Ideas?

p.s. I want it to be case insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into using [full text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) depending on the amount of data you are using.  Otherwise, you can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) to specific a regular expression to search for the word. You should [see this question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126760/mysql-instr-specify-word-boundaries) for a way of using REGEXP to find words.

Comment: can you please give an example of how to do this with regex?

Comment: i used the answer from the post with the following regex: (?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])<word>(?=$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])

Comment: Isn't enough with `/bword/b` ?

Answer (score -1):

use [LIKE operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). like so:

```
select * from table1 where BIO LIKE '%cto%'
```

the '%' indicates a wildcard (meaning- any set of chars).
if you want to find only records that begin with 'cto', use: 'cto%'.
if you want only records that contain cto as a full word (i.e with spaces around it), use:

```
BIO LIKE '% cto %' or BIO LIKE 'cto %' or BIO LIKE 'cto %'
```

(the two Or's i've added are for cases when 'cto' appears at the beginning / end of the string)

Comment: He'd miss `i am a cto/developer` with those `LIKE` conditions and the first query would get many unwanted results (like `ctools`)

Comment: these were meant just as examples. I never intended to solve his exact problem for him, just to demonstrate the use of the 'like' operator.