# How to find documents, which field is a substring to the specific string?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Is there any way to find a document in MongoDB collection, which field is a substring to my *"string"*?

Just a little example. Suppose I have this collection:

```
{"str": "pho", ...},
{"str": "sma", ...},
{"str": "goa", ...},
{"str": "aba", ...},
{"str": "gag", ...}
...
```

And my *"string"* is "smartphone" for example. So the result of the query should be:

```
{"str": "pho", ...}
{"str": "sma", ...}
```

For now I use this regex to solve my problem:

```
^[smartphone]+$
```

That works, but it'll also match documents like `{"str": "ophms", ...}` which "str" is not a substring of "smartphone".

*I know, my question is exact like a [#2123738](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123738/mysql-find-rows-which-have-a-field-that-is-a-substring-of-string), but that's about sql databases, which querying methods differents a lot.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$indexOfCP` to find a string is a substring of other, if yes it will return the starting index otherwise `-1`

```
{$expr : {$gte : [{$indexOfCP: ["smartphone","$str"]},0]}}
```

collection

```
> db.t60.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44c5cc9d56bf65be5ab2de"), "str" : "pho" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44c5cc9d56bf65be5ab2df"), "str" : "sma" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44c5cc9d56bf65be5ab2e0"), "str" : "goa" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44c5cc9d56bf65be5ab2e1"), "str" : "aba" }
```

result

```
> db.t60.find({$expr : {$gte : [{$indexOfCP: ["smartphone","$str"]},0]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44c5cc9d56bf65be5ab2de"), "str" : "pho" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44c5cc9d56bf65be5ab2df"), "str" : "sma" }
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks. But how would you change this query to match documents which contains an list of strings and one of that string is a substring of my word? I mean, `{"str": ["pho", "itu"], ...}` should match the query.

Comment: Can you elaborate, post as a new question and share the link?

Comment: Here it is: [#54307938](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307938/find-documents-which-array-contains-a-string-that-is-a-substring-to-specific-wo)