# Find documents, which array contains a string that is a substring to specific word, using MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Suppose, I have this collection:

```
{"str": ["pho", "goa"], ...},
{"str": ["sma", "aba"], ...},
{"str": ["gag"], ...}
...
```

And I want to select all the documents, which field (`str` here) contains a string, which is a substring to some word. `smartphone` for example. So the result of the query should be:

```
{"str": ["pho", "goa"], ...},
{"str": ["sma", "aba"], ...}
```

How can I do that?

*This question is related to [#54279248](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279248/how-to-find-documents-which-field-is-a-substring-to-the-specific-string), where you don't have to search within array.*

Comment: Use $regex operator with filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$str",
                        as: "s",
                        in: { $ne: [ -1, { $indexOfBytes: [ "smartphone", "$$s" ] } ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The idea is that you can take advantage of [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) to check string from `str` is contained in `"smartphone"` and then you just need to use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) to check if condition is met for any item from `str`

Mongo playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q5zVCo-mkJI)

Comment: Hmm, it works just fine on Mongo playground, but I get this error on my real DB: `$anyElementTrue's argument must be an array, but is null`. I'm a bit frustrated.

Comment: I'll try to solve this problem and write the solution here.

Comment: @PaulLynn that's happening because probably some of your documents does not contain `str` field or it is not an array. Could you verify that ?

Comment: oh, yeah, exactly. `db[collection].find().count() - db[collection].find({ "str": {$type: "array"} }).count()` returned `1`. I've found just an empty document in my collection: `{"_id": ...}`. Is there any sort of filter for aggregation?

Comment: @PaulLynn yes, you can put $type operator inside of $match and check if it returns an array like here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/